# Should we close questions that are too specific/localized?

Tags: discussion

Are questions like this

[How to find the xpath locator for logout button?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16698/how-to-find-the-xpath-locator-for-logout-button)

useful to a wider audience?

There's possibility to close a question as too broad, but there's no way to close it as too specific: an XPath expression that works for one application will not work for another. The only thing people can learn from such questions is the process of finding such an expression. Or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest instead, creating a more generic question about how to find Xpath locators, and then closing very specific questions as duplicates.

Comment: In fact, you could leave the question intact but change the title to something more general.  It's good to have a concrete example in a question.

Comment: Good idea. I have create such generic question: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16995/how-to-generate-proper-locators-for-elements-in-web-pages. Any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

> The only thing people can learn from such questions is the process of finding such an expression.

I agree, but if it teaches them how to find the expression, the question is useful.

Now, the other reason you might close the question is that someone should be able to figure this out for themselves with a Google search, but judging by the quality of the questions, plenty of people have not mastered using Google to answer technical questions.

Answer (score 0):

According to me such questions are more suitable for Software Development forums.

Certain questions related to software testing tools are welcome on SQA according to me.

In this specific question that you mention I still believe it should be closed and as testerab suggested either there should be a general question for it and mark all others as duplicate or better yet have people write answers on it in a forum, this topic would be a good suite for a tutorials site or a technical blog.

Comment: There are questions here that are 100% on topic despite being 100% on topic at another site like SO. There was a separate Selenium proposal that was merged into this one at the last minute (2 weeks before launch, back in April 2011). This site continues to support Selenium and other testing tools that require coding. As for whether the specific question should have a canonical question crafted, I'll leave that to the experts in that area, since that's a technical decision, not a philosophical one.